# Connecting layer 3 switches together without trunking

Tags: switch, vlan, juniper, ospf, ubiquiti

I currently have 2x Juniper EX4200 and I'm looking into changing it into Ubiquiti EdgeSwitchs.

The diagram:

[image]

SW01 and SW02 are connected to each other using OSPF P2P. Both of the switches have their own VLANs and shouldn't be shared (which is I didn't just use a trunk port).

Each switch has a /30 for management and additional subnets for servers.

I was wondering if this is something that would be possible to do in the EdgeSwitch (connect the two switches without sharing the VLANs between them).

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you downgrading from Juniper EX4200 switches to ANYTHING made by Ubiquiti? Ubiquiti devices are nowhere near the same level as what you have already. Is there a reason why you're wanting to switch vendors and quality?

Comment: @JesseP. The reason is that I would like my partners to be able to manage it alone as well. Currently, I run it alone and Ubiquiti is really easy to manage because of the UI. If  this is not possible to do with Ubiquiti, we will most likely keep them and get an online course instead

Comment: According to what I see, EdgeSwitch doesn't support ANY form of dynamic routing. That being said, you could possibly do static routing, but depending on how many subnets you have, that could be a pain the maintain and manage.

Comment: @JesseP. I see, that's unfortunate. thank you for the help, I'll just stick to the Juniper. Also, if you don't mind me asking, what's so bad with Ubiquiti? are they not meant for enterprise as well? because if you google the specs, it shows better capacity than the EX4200.

Comment: No, they're not enterprise-grade. They're, at best, small business/branch-office grade, in my opinion. They don't support MANY of the features that true enterprise-grade devices do, they don't have a good support model (which is a must), they don't play nice with other brands (from personal experience), there are critical bugs that don't get fixed (improper VLAN tags on traffic from completely unrelated ports, for example), etc. There are too many reasons to list. They're cheap, and you get what you pay for. That's not good in the I.T. world. You pay for quality, not quantity.

Comment: Other people on here may have different opinions of experiences, for the record.

Comment: @JesseP. yeah of course. either way, if they don't support dynamic routing they are no use for us.